# Wierd text style inside button in iOS

Tags: html, css

When viewing my site in Windows/Mac/Android or any OS's my site displays just as I want to. But in iOS (on an iPhone, iPod Touch, iPad etc) it makes the text inside a button look wierd.

![][1]

Here you can see the problem occur on an iPad. The button with "Male" is displayed correctly , but the "Female" button is displayed wrong. (the female gender sign is on the top)

Here is the code for the two buttons:

```
<button class="choose">&#9794; Male</button>
<button class="choose">&#9792; Female</button>
```

CSS code:

```
// body code for the whole document:
body{
    font-size:14px;
    font-family:"Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode" Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing:subpixel-antialiased;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

// code just for the two buttons:
    .choose{
        font-size:15px;
        height:40px;
        width:100px;
    }
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using a non-breaking space?

```
<button class="choose">&#9794;&nbsp;Male</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the button style to `.choose{ font-size:15px; height:40px; width:120px; }`. You're not giving the word "female" enough room to fit on the same line as the symbol, so it drops down in an attempt to fit in the button without running off. Increasing the width of the button should fix this.

If that's not the case, I'm lost. It works fine on your website, but it may be that changing the font for iOS is causing the problem--it could be slightly bigger and thus not fitting.

Comment: Good answer, but the problem is that I do not want to expand it and change the size... it kinda changes the design.